# MERN-stack with react-router user authentication without redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, react-router

I'm currently trying to implement some authentication for my application, however, I have a quick question.
I set up some basic authentication on the backend, which sets a token and sends it to the frontend where it is saved in a cookie.
I read that the token is sent to the server any time I'm making an api-call, but I have trouble understanding how I'm supposed to do that.

I just read this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684338/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-and-how-to-save-their-information-react) and it seems as if the person that answers this question simply suggests two helper-functions which check if there is an item called token.
This seems like a bit of a security risk to me. Couldn't anyone just set an item called token which any random value in the local storage? Thus this person would gain access to protected routes?
If so, how would you make sure that the JWT is actually authenticated?

So, to break it down, my questions are:

1. Is what the answer above suggests a security risk?
2. How exactly to you send JWTs with your api-calls and how are they verified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is what the answer above suggests a security risk?

Your api should return a 401 error if a random token is used so you can handle this 401 error by clearing the token value in the cookie/local storage.

**Edit:** To prevent the user to access private routes with a self entered token value you may want to make an api request to check the token in the auth function of your private route (this is optionnal as a fake user will not be able to fetch the api anyway, btw keep in mind that the client have access to the javascript app code so he will always be able to "read" the restricted pages, unless you do SSR, that's why your sensitive data have to be server-side)

> 2. How exactly to you send JWTs with your api-calls and how are they verified?

Depends on your server side implementation i.e. [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) or [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) and [passport-jwt](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt) works great.

On client side you'll send your jwt in the `Authorization` header of each request with a prefix like `JWT` or `Bearer` (depending on passport config).

Example using fetch :

```
fetch('/api', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ...'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have a few routes in my app, a few of which are protected. So, you're saying that it's enough if I check if the token exists and when I'm making api calls to retrieve the users data I simply pass the token as header. How does the backend verifiy the token? I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/of-all-things-tech-progress/starting-with-authentication-a-tutorial-with-node-js-and-mongodb-25d524ca0359 when setting up the authentication on the backend.

Comment: The tutorial you linked use session to authenticate the user so you won't find how to use jwt token in this, you can take a look a this tutorial : https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

Comment: Instead of sessions I just create a token which the server sends in response. Thank you very much for the link!

Comment: Hope this is not too far off, but do you know how I can fetch user-specific data as well? My token stores the user information but how do I use that to get the actual information about that specific user?

Comment: You can use a middleware to decode the JWT ( section 9 in the tutorial i sent you, it sets the decoded user info in `req.decoded`)